# QStackedWidget заполняет собой всю сетку QGridLayout и остальных объектов не видно

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qstackedwidget

Для создания страниц перехода по кнопкам я добавил в код `QStackedWidget`. 
Однако с его добавлением фрейм "`content`" отображает ТОЛЬКО `QStackedWidget` игнорируя `sizeGrip`, который без `StackedWidget` находится внизу окна.

Я пробовал поставить `StackedWidget` в качестве родителя `gridLayout` - результат тот же. 
Я пробовал поставить `label_content` в качестве родителя `stackedWidget` - результат тот же. 
Я пробовал ставить `content` в качестве родителя для `StackedWidget`, а `gridLayout` добавлять внутрь этого `StackedWidget` на первую страницу "page" - тогда всё отображается как надо, но меня не устраивает что необходимую сетку придётся CTRL-C CTRL-V на каждую страницу.

Так же я пробовал вообще убирать `self` из `stackedWidget`, но к моему удивлению даже в этом случае `StackedWidget` отображается перекрывая собой другие элементы (окно закрывал, `__pycache__` удалял, код перед запуском сохранял).

Что я делаю не так? Чувствую что ответ где-то на поверхности, но пока что я не могу понять как мне сделать так, чтобы все элементы отображались на `StackedWidget`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QIcon, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.clicks = 0
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.offset = None
        self.offset_title_bar = False

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.content = QFrame()
        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# Pages
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        #self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(180,110,80);")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.content)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        # vvvvvvvvvvvv Что-то здесь не так
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 0, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)
        sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(
            sizeGrip, 1, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

# left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)

# title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_title = QLabel('Title_bar', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)

# close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-power-standby.png')))
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.label_title is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.offset_title_bar = True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.offset_title_bar = False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект  **`self.content`** вам не нужен вообще.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
        self.clicks = 0
        self.offset = None
        self.offset_title_bar = False

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# ??? 
#        self.content = QFrame()
#        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
#        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,43,50);")

        # Pages
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")
        
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(180,110,80);")

# +++                                           vvvvvvvvv
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.page)         # - (self.content)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        
        # vvvvvvvvvvvv Что-то здесь не так 
#  stackedWidget вставлен ниже в строке -->  self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)        
#        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 0, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)
        sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(
            sizeGrip, 1, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        # left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.button_page = QPushButton('1 Page')
        self.button_page.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.button_page_2 = QPushButton('2 Page')
        self.button_page_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        
        self.vbox_left_bar = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_left_bar.addWidget(self.button_page)
        self.vbox_left_bar.addWidget(self.button_page_2)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


        # title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_title = QLabel('Title_bar', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)

        # close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.label_title is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.offset_title_bar = True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.offset_title_bar = False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Да, я так пробовал. Указывал родителем 1 страницу stackedWidget для gridLayout. Но фрейм с изменением размеров окна оказывался естественно только на первой странице. На второй фрейма нет. Мне нужно чтобы на всех страницах, независимо на какую кнопку я кликнул, была эта QSizeGrip.

Тогда вам надо вставить `QSizeGrip` и на другие страницы.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35,43,50);")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 500)
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        
        self.clicks = 0
        self.offset = None
        self.offset_title_bar = False

        self.top_bar = QFrame()
        self.top_bar.setObjectName('top_bar')
        self.top_bar.setMaximumHeight(40)
        self.top_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

# ??? 
#        self.content = QFrame()
#        self.content.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
#        self.content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,43,50);")

        # Pages
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(120,120,30);")
        
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(180,110,80);")
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.page_2)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content_2 = QLabel(
            'Page 2', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_content_2, 0, 0)
        sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818")        
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(
            sizeGrip, 1, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            

# +++                                           vvvvvvvvv
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.page)         # - (self.content)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_content = QLabel(
            'Hello World', self, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_content.setStyleSheet("background-color: #064635")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_content, 0, 0)
        
        # vvvvvvvvvvvv Что-то здесь не так 
#  stackedWidget вставлен ниже в строке -->  self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)        
#        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 0, 1)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        font = self.label_content.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label_content.setFont(font)
        sizeGrip = QtWidgets.QSizeGrip(self)
        sizeGrip.setStyleSheet("background-color: #CD1818")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(
            sizeGrip, 1, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        # left_bar
        self.left_bar = QFrame()
        self.left_bar.setMinimumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setMaximumWidth(50)
        self.left_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.StyledPanel | QFrame.Raised)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.button_page = QPushButton('1 Page')
        self.button_page.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.button_page_2 = QPushButton('2 Page')
        self.button_page_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        
        self.vbox_left_bar = QVBoxLayout(self.left_bar)
        self.vbox_left_bar.addWidget(self.button_page)
        self.vbox_left_bar.addWidget(self.button_page_2)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


        # title_bar
        self.title_bar = QFrame()
        self.title_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent")
        self.title_bar.setMinimumWidth(120)
        self.gridLayout2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.title_bar)
        self.gridLayout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout2.setSpacing(0)
        self.label_title = QLabel('Title_bar', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_title.setObjectName('label_title')
        self.label_title.setStyleSheet("background-color: #519259")
        font = self.label_title.font()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_title.setFont(font)
        self.label_title.installEventFilter(self)
        self.gridLayout2.addWidget(self.label_title, 0, 0)

        # close_button
        self.close_button = QPushButton()
        self.close_button.setIcon(
            QIcon(QPixmap('Ok.png')))
        self.close_button.setMinimumHeight(40)
        self.close_button.setMaximumWidth(40)
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.close_window)

        self.layout_navigation = QGridLayout(self.top_bar)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.title_bar, 0, 0)
        self.layout_navigation.addWidget(self.close_button, 0, 3)
        self.layout_navigation.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.right_bar = QFrame()
        self.right_bar.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)

        self.vbox_2 = QVBoxLayout(self.right_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.top_bar)
        self.vbox_2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.vbox_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vbox_2.setSpacing(0)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.hbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.hbox.setSpacing(0)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.left_bar)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.right_bar)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.label_title is obj:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.offset_title_bar = True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.offset_title_bar = False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def close_window(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я так пробовал. Указывал родителем  1 страницу stackedWidget для gridLayout. Но фрейм с изменением размеров окна оказывался естественно только на первой странице. На второй фрейма нет. Мне нужно чтобы на всех страницах, независимо на какую кнопку я кликнул, была эта QSizeGrip.

Comment: @PandaStock я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: Благодарю. А есть ли какие-то способы не добавлять это на каждую страницу? Я бы сделал функцию с аргументом page1 или page2, но в Pyqt функция указывается без параметров, потому передача аргументов невозможна.

Comment: @PandaStock все можно сделать по-разному. Кто вам сказал что передача аргументов в функцию невозможна? Я бы вам посоветовал страницы, которые вы помещаете в `stackedWidget`, вообще поместить в отдельные  классы. Код будет чище и понятнее. А классы наследовать от `QMainWindow`, в котором активировать `self.statusBar()`, в котором уже есть `QSizeGrip`. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Так и сделаю.

Comment: @PandaStock пожалуйста.